# can a Sesioon state be locked

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 ASP.NET framework.I followed that a Application state can be locked like

```
Application.Lock();
Application["PageRequestCount"] = 
((int)Application["PageRequestCount"])+1;
Application.UnLock();
```

Similarly a session state can be locked? if yes how? if not then why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Application.Lock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx) method blocks other clients from modifying the variables stored in the Application object, ensuring that only one client at a time can alter or access the Application variables.

Where as Session is for Individual Users, There is no need for locking it and protecting it from other users